# "Backand is not defined" after angular js quickstart

Tags: angularjs, backand

I get this error when I'm trying to use simple CRUD action

> ReferenceError: Backand is not defined

I did everything step by step like they requested but something is wrong and I can figure out what... thanks!

Comment: And how are we supposed to know without any sort of code or information? Use some common sense when asking a question please.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you do this stuffs:

1. Add backand sdk as script in your index.html files.

   src="//cdn.backand.net/backand/dist/1.8.2/backand.min.js"
2. Add 'backand' as angular module dependency

   angular.module('YOUR-APP-NAME', ['backand'])
3. In your controller add Backand with 'B' uppercase.

   myApp.controller('SimpleController', function(Backand){
   })